# axios.put() with formData react axios not send req.params.id === undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux

i have a component in react with redux to update values for products with this code.

**component Code:**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import FormData from "form-data";
import { editarProductoActionUser} from "../actions/productoActions";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

//STYLED COMPONENTS
const Label = styled.label`
  font-family: Anton;
`;

const TextArea = styled.textarea`
  font-family: Lato;
`;

//FUNCION PARA EDITAR PRODUCTO

const EditarProducto = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  
  //OPCIONES DESDE NUEVO PRODUCTO
  const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState("");
  const [subCategoria, setSubCategoria] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [images, setImage] = useState("");
  const [id, setId] = useState('');

  const productoEditar = useSelector((state) => state.productos.productoeditar);
  console.log(productoEditar.images[0].filename)
 // TOMAMOS DEL STATE DEL PROUDUCTO EL ID PARA PODER PASARLO A LA NUEVA FUNCION DEL DISPATCH Y ASÍ 
 // PODER PASAR LOS DATOS AL SERVIDOR Y NO TENER EL ERROR 'UNDEFINED'
  const productoId = productoEditar._id
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setId(productoId)
    setCategoria(productoEditar.categoria)
    setSubCategoria(productoEditar.subCategoria)
    setTitle(productoEditar.title)
    setPrice(productoEditar.price)
    setDescription(productoEditar.description)
    setImage(productoEditar.images[0].url)
    //setProductoEditado(productoEditar);
  }, [productoEditar, productoId]);

//console.log(productoEditar.categoria)

  const editarProductoUser = (producto ) =>
    dispatch(editarProductoActionUser(producto));
     
  const submitEditarProducto = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();      

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("images", images);
    formData.set("title", title);
    formData.set("categoria", categoria);
    formData.set("subCategoria", subCategoria);
    formData.set("price", price);
    formData.set("description", description);
    formData.set('id', id) //PASAMOS EL ID COMO UN STATE MÁS CON EL PRODUCTO, PARA SABER QUE PRODUCTO ESTAMOS E
   setId(productoEditar._id)

    editarProductoUser(formData)
    
    //console.log(formData);
    history.push("/productos");
  };

  
  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-8">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="text-center mx-auto font-wight-bold mb-5">
                EDITAR Producto
              </h2>
              <form onSubmit={submitEditarProducto}>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Label className="mb-2">Selecciona el tipo de producto</Label>
                  <select
                    className="custom-select form-control"
                    defaultValue={categoria}
                    name="categoria"
                    value={categoria}
                    onChange={(e) => setCategoria(e.target.value)}
                    // onChange={onChangeFormularioEditado}
                  >
                    
                    <option value="tabla">Tabla</option>
                    <option value="vela">Vela</option>
                    <option value="botavara">Botavara</option>
                    <option value="mastil">Mastil</option>
                    <option value="accesorio">Accesorio</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Label className="mb-2">Selecciona la Categoria</Label>
                  <select
                    className="custom-select form-control"
                    defaultValue={subCategoria}
                    name="subCategoria"
                    value={subCategoria} 
                    onChange={(e) => setSubCategoria(e.target.value)}
                    // onChange={onChangeFormularioEditado}
                  >
                    
                    
                    <option value="slalom">Slalom</option>
                    <option value="freeride">Free-Ride</option>
                    <option value="freerace">Free-Race</option>
                    <option value="freestyle">Free-Style</option>
                    <option value="foil">Foil</option>
                    <option value="waves">Waves</option>
                    <option value="carbono">Carbono</option>
                    <option value="aluminio">Aluminio</option>
                    <option value="mixta">Mixta</option>
                    <option value="rdm">RDM</option>
                    <option value="sdm">SDM</option>
                    <option value="aleta">ALETA</option>
                    <option value="arnes">ARNES</option>
                    <option value="alargador">ALARGADOR</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Label htmlFor="tituloProducto" className="form-label">
                    Producto
                  </Label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="title"
                    value={title}
                    id="title"
                    placeholder="Tabla Slalom ...."
                    onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                  ></input>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Label htmlFor="precioProducto" className="form-label">
                    Precio
                  </Label>
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="precioProducto"
                    placeholder="450"
                    name="price"
                    value={price}
                    onChange={(e) => setPrice(Number(e.target.value))}
                  ></input>
                </div>

                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Label htmlFor="descripcionProducto" className="form-label">
                    Descripción del Producto
                  </Label>
                  <TextArea
                    className="form-control"
                    id="descripcionProducto"
                    rows="3"
                    name="description"
                    value={description}
                    onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                  ></TextArea>
                </div>
                <img
                  className="card-img-top"
                  src={images}
                  alt="imagen nula"
                ></img>
                <div>
                  <input
                    className="form-input"
                    id="images"
                    type="file"
                    name="images"
                    //value={images}
                    onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
                  ></input>
                </div>

                <div className="mb-3 text-center">
                  <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                    Editar Producto
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditarProducto;
```

**action code:**

```
//COLOCAR PRODUCTO EN EDICIÓN
export function obtenerProductoEditarActionUser(producto) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch (obtenerProductoEditar(producto))    
    console.log(producto)
  }
}

const obtenerProductoEditar = producto => ({
  type: OBTENER_PRODUCTO_EDITAR,
  payload: producto
})

export function editarProductoActionUser(producto){ 
  console.log(producto)
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch (editarProductoUser(producto));
    
    
    try {
        const editarRespuesta = await clienteAxios.put(`/api/productos/user/editar/${producto._id}` , producto, data )       
        console.log(editarRespuesta.data)
       
        dispatch(editarProductoUserExito(producto))  

       Swal.fire(
        'Correcto',
        'El Producto se editó Correctamente',
        'success'
      ).then(function() {
        window.location = "/productos"})
      
      console.log(producto)    
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      dispatch(editarProductoUserError())
      
    }
  }
}

const editarProductoUser = (producto) => ({
  type: COMENZAR_EDICION_PRODUCTO,
  payload: producto
})

const editarProductoUserExito = (producto) => ({
  type: PRODUCTO_EDITADO_EXITO,
  payload: producto
})

const editarProductoUserError = (estado) => ({
  type: PRODUCTO_EDITADO_ERROR,
  payload: estado
})
```

**reducers: (it's the extract for this case)**

```
case OBTENER_PRODUCTO_EDITAR:
      return {
        ...state,
        productoeditar: action.payload,
      }
    case PRODUCTO_EDITADO_EXITO:
      return {
        ...state,
        productoeditar: null,
        productos: state.productos.map((producto) =>
          producto.id === action.payload.id
            ? (producto = action.payload)
            : producto
        )
      };
```

**BACKEND CODE**

**index**

```
app.use('/api/productos', require('./routes/productos'))// PARA MANEJAR LOS PRODUCTOS
```

**routes**

```
//ACTUALIZAR PRODUCTOS DE USUARIO
router.put("/user/editar/:id", 
auth, 
//(req,res)=>{(console.log('producto : ' + req.body._id))},
parser.single('images'),

productController.editarProductoUser);
```

**controller**

```
//OBTENER PRODUCTO EDITAR
exports.obtenerProductoEditar = async (req,res) => {
  try {
    const productoEditarId = await Producto.findById(req.params.id);
   // console.log('el producto :' + productoEditarId)
    res.json({productoEditarId});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).send('Hubo un Error')
    
  }
}

//EDITAR UN PRODUCTO
exports.editarProductoUser = async (req, res) => {
   
  console.log("hola antes del primer print");
  // const {id} = req.params
  // console.log('el id es:  ' + id)
 
  //   //REVISAR SI HAY ERRORES
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  //CREAMOS EL NUEVO OBJETO PARA EDITAR A PARTIR DE LOS VALORES EDITADOS EN EL FORMULARIO
  let newData = {    
    categoria: req.body.categoria,
    subCategoria: req.body.subCategoria,
    title: req.body.title,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,
    images: {     
      url: req.file.path,
      filename: req.file.filename,
    },
  };

  try {
    //   //REVISAR EL ID
    let producto = await Producto.findById(req.params.id);
  // console.log(producto);

    //   //SI EL PRODUCTO EXISTE O NO!!!
    if (!producto) {
      console.log("hay un error en edicion");
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Producto no encontrado" });
    }

    // //   //Verificar el PRODUCTO
    if (producto.author.toString() !== req.user.id) {
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No Autorizado para Editar" });
    }

    //ACTUALIZAR PRODUCTO

    producto = await Producto.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id }, 
      { $set: newData },
      { new: true }
    );
    console.log(producto);
    res.json({ producto });
    //await producto.save()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Hubo un Error");
  }
};
```

when i try to update from postman, works perfectly.
when i try to upadate from client, not works, tell me, all the time....this messages:
***Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model***
***Cannot read property 'path' of undefined***

if i try to changes req.params for req.body, to extract the id, then works from client, but not from postman....

Please, some light to help me.
thanks

**I SOLVED IT**
i had the solution in front of my eyes....
i just pass the id inside the formData. So in the action, just need to get the id, and put in the axios adress.

**in the action**

```
    export function editarProductoAction(producto){ 
   //use to get the id from formData
  const productoId = producto.getAll('id');        
  console.log(productoId)
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch (editarProducto());      
    try {
        const editarRespuesta = await 
      clienteAxios.put(`/api/productos/user/editar/${productoId}` 
       , 
       producto, data )       
        console.log(editarRespuesta.data)       
        dispatch(editarProductoUserExito(producto))  

       Swal.fire(
        'Correcto',
        'El Producto se editó Correctamente',
        'success'
      ).then(function() {
        window.location = "/productos"})
      
      console.log(producto)    
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      dispatch(editarProductoUserError())
      
    }
  }
 }
```

Now works perfect. the server call req.params.id and find the product.id, to change the product data.

Comment: you haven't added backend code where this error generate. please add it to get ans

Comment: oh sorry, i did think that only was necessary the front-end, because the backend works perfect with postman. Now i edit my question and put the backend code.